# Measuring thread migrations on Linux

Tags: multithreading, migration, pthreads

Could some one direct me to a command or a way on Linux to measure the number of migrations experienced by a thread or a process? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have a better tool, but you can use `perf` tool for that.

> Perf is a profiler tool for Linux 2.6+ based systems that abstracts
>   away CPU hardware differences in Linux performance measurements and
>   presents a simple commandline interface. Perf is based on the
>   perf_events interface exported by recent versions of the Linux kernel.

I have never personally used it, but on their [website](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/) you have a [tutorial](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial) and an output example of [Counting with perf stat](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Counting_with_perf_stat), where the number of migrations is part of the output.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. But the data getting from the tool is somewhat mysterious. So much variation from run to run.

Comment: The data that you are collecting depends on a number of factors such as the load of your system, the scheduling policy, input/output operations etc. Most probably, the variations that you are obtaining in the data that you are analyzing are due to those factors.